# Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, via algebra

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I know there are already a couple of questions on this on the site, but I haven't seen an answer to this particular form...

We know, from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, that the complex algebraic numbers contain a unique maximal ordered subfield, namely the real algebraic numbers, and the complex algebraic numbers are obtained by adjoining a square root of $-1$ to the real algebraic numbers.

This is a purely algebraic statement (I think!) and one could reasonably ask for a purely algebraic proof. Is there such a proof? Or is there a barrier to such a proof (such as a model of ZF where the statement is false)?

I'm aware of the standard (purely algebraic, or at least I'm happy to call it so) Zorn's Lemma proof that the complex algebraic numbers exist, since any field $K$ has an algebraic closure and this is unique up to isomorphism. However the 'up to isomorphism' here includes a great many isomorphisms of the complex algebraic numbers that fix the rationals. I think a more or less equivalent question to what I am asking is: from this construction, is there a good algebraic way to pick out the privileged automorphism $i\to-i$ and put an order on the subfield this automorphism fixes?

There do exist proofs of the usual Fundamental Theorem of Algebra which use a `minimal' amount of analysis, such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05609 (due to Piotr Błaszczyk) which doesn't really use more analysis than required to define the reals. However even this is more than (I think!) I am asking for.

Comment: It isn't a purely algebraic statement since you can't define the complex numbers in a purely algebraic fashion. The complex numbers are much bigger than an algebraic closure of the rationals.

Comment: I agree with the other comment. FTA is by far more of an analytic statement than an algebraic one because $\mathbb C$ is an analytic object more so than an algebraic one. However, I am interested in your other question, which I would phrase as asking to show algebraically that an algebraically closed field in characteristic 0 has an order 2 automorphism.

Comment: I'm well aware that there are many more complex numbers than complex algebraic numbers - but that's the entire point of this question. The linked arxiv proof already shows that 'all' you need to prove FTA in the usual form is the Dedekind description of the reals, which is basically the same as constructing $\mathbb{C}$. But I don't see that talking about 'complex algebraic numbers' means you need to talk about the complex numbers as a whole. I agree it's slightly sloppy language, but, if you prefer, take it as simply meaning the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Completely without analysis you can't. Otherwise you could prove that every equation with rational coefficients has solutions in ${\mathbb Q}(i)$. The very definition of $\mathbb R$ involves some analysis. The one "most algebraic" proof I know uses two facts that require some analysis:

(1) If $a>0$ then the equation $X^2-a=0$ has a real root.

(2)  Every polynomial of odd degree has a real root.

If we write the degree of $P\in{\mathbb R}[X]$ as $n=2^km$, with $m$ odd, then the proof is done by induction on $k$.

Comment: @Wojowu - I'm not exactly an expert, nor did I think too much - but isn't it more or less obvious that there is such an automorphism, precisely because $x^2+1=0$ has two solutions which are necessarily conjugate and not in the base field? But this applies equally well to $x^2-2=0$. The point is that the first automorphism fixes a subfield which we happen to know is ordered, whereas (I think - actually one should maybe check this properly!) the second does not. Again, though, the only way I know how to order the first subfield goes via constructing $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @user36212 This only guarantees that there is an automorphism which swaps $i$ with $-i$, but not that this automorphism has order $2$ (i.e. $\sigma(\sigma(x))=x$ for *all* $x$ in the field). As some food for thought, one can show that there cannot be any automorphism of finite order larger than $2$, so however you want to show that an order $2$ automorphism exists, you have to somehow make significant use of the number $2$.

Comment: Constantin-Nicolae - I don't see this; for example I can happily show $\sqrt{2}$ isn't rational, and adjoin an element $x$ such that $x^2-2=0$, to obtain a bigger field than $\mathbb{Q}$, without having to construct the reals. If you give me anything isomorphic to a subfield of the reals, then I know (but I only know via analysis) I can put an order on that field; if you give me a field containing a solution to $x^2+1=0$ then I can (trivially and algebraically) prove there is no order on the field.

Comment: @Wojowu - good point. I'm tempted to say this should follow from the fact that the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same as the field of $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraic numbers. But either this is so obviously true I don't see why, or there is a gap...
In any case, I also don't see (maybe due to my stupidity) how to put an order on the subfield this automorphism fixes without invoking some analysis. This is what I would really like to be able to do, because for me a fundamental characteristic of $\mathbb{R}$ and its subfields is that there is an order.

Comment: @user36212 Actually, it need not be true that an automorphism of a field swapping the two roots of $x^2+1$ has totally orderable fixed field. This of course happens for the complex conjugation, but needn't happen to other such automorphisms.

Comment: To make an algebraic statement with algebric proof  you first have to DEFINE "real algebraic numbers" without using complex numbers.

Comment: A purely algebraic definition of $\mathbb C$ is "an algebraically closed, characteristic-0 field of cardinality the continuum."  (Inside here we can pick out the algebraic numbers as the algebraic closure of the embedded copy of $\mathbb Q$.)  This is also a definition of $\overline{\mathbb Q_\ell}$.  If we could pick out $\mathbb R$ canonically inside $\mathbb C$, what would we be picking out inside $\overline{\mathbb Q_\ell}$?  (Just thinking out loud.)

Comment: We have the following statement: Every polynomial over a field $K$ has a root in $K(\sqrt{-1})$. Then FTA says the statement is true for $K=\mathbb R$. Obviously, it's not true for every field $K$, we need some properties. A minimal set of properties would be: (1) $X^4-a^2$ has a root in $K$ for every $a\in K$, (2) Every polynomial in $K[X]$ of odd degree has a root in $K$, (3) $K$ is not finite. (Note that (1) simply states that either $a$ or $-a$ has a square root in $K$.)

Comment: @Constantin-NicolaeBeli I believe your (3) follows from (2).

Comment: One relevant (negative) result is that there is no first-order definition of the real algebraic numbers in the structure $(\mathbb{C}^{alg},+,\cdot)$.

Comment: @Wojowu I forgot to mention that $F$ is not of characteristic $2$. In characteristic $2$ we have equations of the type $X^2+X+a=0$, which have roots in the so called Artin-Schreier extensions.

Comment: @Wojowu You are right, (3) is superfluous, but it doesn't always follow from (1). If $K={\mathbb F}_q$, where $q$ is a prime power, $q\equiv 3\pmod 4$, then $-1$ is not a square in $K$ so for every $a\in K^*$ exactly one of $\pm a$ is a square. If $q\equiv 1$ then for half of the values of $a\in K^*$ both $\pm a$ are squares and for the other half neither of them is, so (1) fails. In all cases though, (3) follows from (2). If $P=X^q-X+1$, with odd degree $q$, then for every $a\in K$ we have $P(a)=1$ so $P$ has no roots in $K$ so (2) fails.

Comment: @Wojowu My mistake. I thought you meant (3) follows from (1), but you actually said it follows from (2), which is right.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko - what I’d like to say is a definition is: the subfield admitting an order and such that adding $i$ we get the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. If this isn’t a definition (I.e. there are multiple such subfields) then you’ve answered my question in the negative. Or at least this is the main thing I’d like to know; I might come up with something more to ask if your examples suggest I should just add another algebraic condition to the above ‘definition’.

Comment: @Matt F. - that sounds interesting, do you have a reference? I guess ‘admitting an order’ is not a first order condition, but still.

Comment: @Wojowu - and is it possible that there is an automorphism of the algebraics which swaps the roots of $x^2+1=0$, the fixed subfield doesn't have an order, and also adding $i$ back to the fixed subfield gives us the entire algebraics? (Actually I'd be very interested to see an example with only the first two of these three properties, do you have a reference?)

Comment: @user36212 No, what you describe is not possible. It follows from Artin-Schreier Theorem as stated e.g. [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) (Theorem 3.1). For the latter question, consider the field $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{-2})$. It has an automorphism which takes $i$ to $-i$ but fixes $\sqrt{-2}$. We can extend this automorphism to $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: @user36212, The reference is just to quantifier elimination: the only first-order definable subsets of $\mathbb{C}^{alg}$ are Boolean combinations of sets of the form $\{z: p(z)=0\}$, which are all either finite or co-finite, and therefore can’t be $\mathbb{R}^{alg}$. Meanwhile, it’s true that “$S$ admits an order” is not a first-order condition, but “the squares in  $S$ define an order on $S$” is first-order.

Comment: I posted a comment to Timothy Chow's answer that I think is also relevant to the discussion here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Despite the extensive discussion in the comments, I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but I think the following fact may settle the question in the negative.

Work of Läuchli implies that there is a model of ZF in which $\mathbb Q$ has an algebraic closure with no real-closed subfield.  For more details, see for example Wilfrid Hodges, "Läuchli's algebraic closure of $Q$," *Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc.* **79** (1976), 289–297.

I think your desired conclusion requires every algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ to have a real-closed subfield.  If you agree, then the above result shows that you at least need some weak form of AC, which arguably is "not algebraic."  But this depends on what you mean by "algebraic"; maybe a weak form of choice doesn't automatically disqualify a proof from being "algebraic"?

Comment: Thanks! I think that's exactly what I was looking for. As you say, it would still be interesting to know how much of AC one needs to kill models of this type; and it would be interesting to know how 'analytic' the proof has to get (which, I think is an I know-it-when-I-see-it question).

Comment: @user36212 : Although you've accepted my answer, I feel that I should mention a couple of caveats. Without AC, one cannot even prove that all algebraic closures of $\mathbb Q$ are isomorphic. Conversely, if we allow enough choice to prove uniqueness, then it sounds like you still feel that everything is "algebraic." So maybe AC is not really getting at your question? What's wrong with this: construct a specific algebraic closure, pick out $i\to-i$, and then carry it over to any other algebraic closure using AC? This doesn't use any "analysis" does it?

Comment: Some questions. The statement:

$\forall P\in \mathbb{Q}[X], \exists a\in \mathbb{Q}[i] \text{ such that } |P(a)|\le 1$

1) is it "purely algebraic"?

2) is it true in Läuchli's model?

3) is it then provable in a "purely algebraic" way? (No AC, or whatever "purely algebraic" may mean...) That to me would amount as close as can be to an algebraic proof of the Fundamental Theorem.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch, what to call algebraic is a matter of personal opinion, but I personally would not use the phrase "purely algebraic" for $|P(a)|\le 1$.

Comment: @MattF. : Why not? Suppose we write it this way: $\exists (p+qi) \in {\mathbb Q}[i]$ such that $p^2 + q^2 \le 1$. The only objection I can think of is that the order relation on the integers is "not algebraic." The OP seems to think that Zorn's lemma is okay, so why not the order relation on the integers? It seems a bit of a stretch to call the order relation on the integers "analytic".

Comment: @MattF. I'm inclined to agree with you. I was myself thinking that the order relation is the spoiler, and I cannot think of a statement that avoids using it while still managing to capture the spirit of the Fund. Thm.

Comment: @TimothyChow, I like the clarity of first-order logic. So I would call order a part of the algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ (because $a\ge b \leftrightarrow \exists c (a=b+c^2)$) or $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ (because of the four-squares definition). But I would not call norms or conjugates part of the algebra of $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}[i]$ or $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ or $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, where they are not definable from the ring operations.

Comment: @TimothyChow: norms even allow to do away with order without existence predicates, since $|a|\le 1$ is equivalent to $|a|+|1-|a||=1$. So I now agree with Matt F. that norms lead into a non-algebraic landscape.

Comment: @MattF. : Okay, I think I see what you mean. The question then seems to be a (near-)duplicate of [this question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97082). In particular, it remains unclear what "the fundamental theorem of algebra" even *means* in such a framework, let alone whether it can be proved.

Comment: Update: Norms actually can be defined algebraically for $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[i]$. This follows from Julia Robinson's 1958 result (in "The Undecidability of Algebraic Rings and Fields") that $\mathbb{Z}$ can be defined in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ can be defined in $\mathbb{Q}[i]$. The first definition is even short: $n$ is an integer iff (quantifying over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$) $$\exists f,g,h(\tau(0,f,g,h)\wedge\forall a(\tau(a,f,g,h)\implies a=n\vee\tau(a+1,f,g,h)))$$ $$\text{where }\tau(a,f,g,h)\text{ abbreviates }(f\neq 0)\wedge (a+1|f)\wedge (a+2|f)\wedge (1+ag|h)$$

Comment: @MattF. This result seems quite amazing. Is there any remaining obstruction to a potentially purely algebraic proof of the above? (Non-constant rational polynomials on $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ taking values arbitrarily close to 0.)

Comment: @YaakovBaruch, I’d be interested to see what that statement and that proof would look like! It probably goes easier as a statement about homogeneous polynomials in two variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @Timothy Chow - my interest here is that I'm happy to teach (first year undergrad) students some standard analytic proof of FTA, but I've never been quite sure what I should answer (beyond 'well, I don't know how to avoid it') if a student asked why we need analysis to prove this; not that one ever did. So your answer would let me say: even if we are generous enough to assume there is an algebraic closure of the rationals, we can't prove that this algebraic closure looks like the complex numbers without doing something that (these) students will identify as not like algebra they know.

Comment: These students are for sure not going to be happy with Zorn's lemma (not least because they don't know anything like axiomatic set theory) and hence would not likely want to know about different models of ZF, but at least I am happy that I could answer the hypothetical question now...

Comment: @user36212 : In a 1st-year undergrad context, surely FTA just means "$\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed" rather than the convoluted "purely algebraic" statements we are struggling to devise? If so, then it would seem that the trivial answer suffices: analysis is needed even to *state* FTA.

Comment: Sure; and that's how I stated it too. But then I started thinking about how I would answer questions along this line... Like most such courses we build up to this via integers / rationals / (sloppily) reals, and make fairly heavy use of the order along the way, and then introduce the complex numbers as what you get when you have the reals and want to solve $x^2+1=0$, and then magic occurs that in fact this turns out to be algebraically closed. Now the magic has really already occurred when we construct the reals here, so (at least I think) it's natural to ask whether we need that.

Comment: Or to put it another way: can we go from the rationals directly to a countable  algebraic closure with the structure we see in the Argand plane, namely there are two ordered axes, without having to go via something uncountable? Of course what the students would like is a proof that just uses a bunch of high-school algebraic manipulations as with the quadratic formula, which I can happily tell them doesn't exist and go read Abel if they want to know more. But that's not really ruling out a more serious 'algebraic' proof.

Comment: Of course, no student ever asked me anything close to this kind of thing; realistically, they're probably happy enough if they think they more or less understand how the standard proof works. That doesn't stop me from wanting to know what answer I might give such a hypothetical student.

Comment: @user36212 : It might be worth stating more precisely what you mean by "go from the rationals directly to a countable algebraic closure with the structure we see in the Argand plane." This is a somewhat different question from what I thought you were asking. It is provable in a very logically weak system that there *exists* an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$, because you can just construct it directly from polynomial equations. It's only *uniqueness* that requires some form of choice. Proving that this specific algebraic closure has the properties you want may not require "analysis".

Comment: This is a good point. OK, I guess I would like to know the existence of an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, which is countable, and which contains an ordered subfield such that adjoining a square root of $-1$ we get the entire field. Your answer says I can't hope that all such algebraic closures have this structure without using some choice, so at least I'd better be paying attention to the construction...
I don't immediately see how to construct an algebraic closure without any choice; don't I at some point need choice to decide which polynomial to adjoin a root of next?

Comment: I agree that use of choice is probably not really what I want to exclude with 'algebraic'; I think I really would like to avoid having to construct the reals or otherwise do something morally equivalent along the way. I certainly agree that as far as the students are concerned I won't ever need to know this - but I would still like to understand it better.

Comment: @user36212 : [This math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/114984) explains how to construct an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ without Zorn's lemma. The main point is that $\mathbb N$ is already given to us with a well ordering, so we can well order $\mathbb Q$ and all polynomials with rational coefficients without having to ask Zorn to do it for us. The part I'm not immediately sure about is proving the existence of the real closed subfield you want. I suspect this is straightforward but there are details to check.

Comment: I think one just needs to walk through the proof of the Artin-Schreier theorem and check that in the specific case of $\mathbb Q$, one doesn't need Zorn.

Comment: Thanks! I can believe Artin-Schreier might be choice free; it certainly looks like algebra rather than analysis. But doesn‘t it leave the possibility that the constructed closure doesn‘t have any finite index real closed subfield? (Actually this must be what happens in the Läuchli model you referenced, so one needs to see somehow that the construction of a closure doesn‘t accidentally pick this closure)

Comment: Maybe this statement can be proved in arithmetic (by repeated interval bisection)? $\forall N,d \in \mathbb{N}, a_1,...,a_d \in \mathbb{Z}, d$ odd $\implies \exists m,n,t_1,..,t_4 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2+t_4^2+N^2(m^d+a_1nm^{d-1}+...+a_dn^d)^2 = n^{2d}$ (meaning $|(f(m/n)| \leq 1/N$).

Comment: @user36212 : I'm feeling more confident that you can construct something that has all the properties you want, without AC and without "analysis." Even without AC, one can prove that all *countable* algebraic closures of $\mathbb Q$ are isomorphic. If we construct an algebraic closure by lexicographically ordering $\mathbb Q$ and then lexicographically ordering polynomials over $\mathbb Q$, adjoining roots one by one, then the algebraic closure is countable by construction, so no funny business can occur.

Comment: For some further comments, see the [Foundations of Mathematics mailing list](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2020-January/thread.html), specifically the thread about Artin-Schreier for Q.

Comment: @MattF. $d$ is an odd number.